# Sending mail to multiple recipients in smtp sendmail

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

I am using the following code to send the mail ,

```
public function sendMail($mailTo, $subject) {   
       //$mailTo is an array like  array(test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com)  
        $mailto = implode(', ', $mailTo);
        $subject = empty($subject) ? 'Testing Manuel Lemos SMTP class' : $subject;
        require("smtp.php");
        /* Uncomment when using SASL authentication mechanisms */
        require("sasl.php");
        $from = "mlemos@acm.org";                           /* Change this to your address like "me@mydomain.com"; */ $sender_line = __LINE__;
        $to = "$mailto";

     if ($smtp->SendMessage(
                        $from, 
                        array($to)
                        , array(
                    "From: $from",
                    "To: $to",
                    "Subject: TESTMAIL NOTIFICATION",
                    "Date: " . strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
                        ), "Hello $to,$subject \n Bye .")) {
            $str = "Message sent to $to OK.\n";
            return $str;
        } else
            $str = "Could not send the message to $to.\nError: " . $smtp->error . "\n";

}
```

I have the sendMessage function in smtp.php as follows

```
Function SendMessage($sender,$recipients,$headers,$body)
    {            
        if(($success=$this->Connect()))
        {
            if(($success=$this->MailFrom($sender)))
            {
                for($recipient=0;$recipient<count($recipients);$recipient++)
                {
                    if(!($success=$this->SetRecipient($recipients[$recipient])))
                        break;
                }
                if($success
                && ($success=$this->StartData()))
                {
                    for($header_data="",$header=0;$header<count($headers);$header++)
                        $header_data.=$headers[$header]."\r\n";
                    $success=($this->SendData($header_data."\r\n")
                        && $this->SendData($this->PrepareData($body))
                        && $this->EndSendingData());
                }
            }
            $error=$this->error;
            $disconnect_success=$this->Disconnect($success);
            if($success)
                $success=$disconnect_success;
            else
                $this->error=$error;
        }
        return($success);
    }
```

but its not sending the email however , but its sending for the single mail .
when we specify the $to as 'test@gmail.com' . please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you `implode()` the recipients? 
It seems that `SendMessage` can handle multiple recipients passed as array:

```
$smtp->SendMessage('sender@example.tld', array('test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com') ... );
```

In `SendMessage` `SetRecipient` is called for every entry in `$recipients`:

```
for($recipient=0;$recipient<count($recipients);$recipient++)
{
  if(!($success=$this->SetRecipient($recipients[$recipient])))
    break;
}
```

You should avoid passing the "To" header the way you do, when you are dealing with multiple recipients, though.